# Accessing rw_groups after new LinkedIn API policy changes

Tags: api, linkedin-api

Is there any way to access rw_groups in the new api of LinkedIn.
I want to use it for an app which allows my group posts to show on my webpage.

Can it be achieved after apply-with-linked or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

For access to `rw_groups`,  you will have to apply to become a member of a relevant [Partner Program](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs) that provides the necessary API access to `rw_groups` endpoint.

Apply for partner status with LinkedIn, explaining what your integration is and how it works. If it meets the criteria of **"we feel that they’re providing value to members, developers and LinkedIn,"** then `rw_groups` endpoint will remain open for that app, and ONLY that app.

Comment: and let's suppose I have written some code with the help of which any person (with the help of their app credentials) can fetch their group data using it in their websites, then it means every user has to do this tedious task. And all this with a uncertainty that whether it will be approved or not. I think then my code is of no use with this new API now.

Comment: Here, `app` refers to the application 'XYZ' you have built and applied for the Linkedin partner program. Now, once given permission your application `XYZ` has access to the `rw_groups` permission. Even if multiple people use your application, user doesn't have to apply for permission. In OAuth terminology, `Client` is the 3rd party application and not the users using that application('Resource Owner'). You get access for the `Client`.

Comment: No offense, but I know that. What I want to say is, I created an app for Joomla in which user have to fill parameters based on their app 'XYZ', now corresponding to their app credentials their group data will show up in module. Now if my app is being used by 10 people for 10 different websites for 10 different groups, it all results to 10 different apps and rw_groups

Comment: Does the 10 different websites all have the linkedin button to fetch groups values? if yes, then unfortunately you would have to apply for permissions for each of the 10 apps(10 websites).

Comment: Yes it does have it. Ok. But I am not leaving this question open, if somehow it could be done and anyone knows it. Thank you.